# To create loop that lets my regression formula include one variable each tome

Tags: python, loops

I've been working on stepwise regression. To do so I'll find a loop that lets my regression formula include one variable each time, but I'm having some trouble with the loop. The code is as follows:

```
def forward_selected(data, response):
    remaining = set(data.columns)
    remaining.remove(response)
    selected = []
    current_aic, best_new_aic = 0.0, 0.0
    while remaining and current_aic == best_new_aic:
        aics_with_candidates = []
        for candidate in remaining:
            formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,' + '.join(selected +     [candidate]))
            aic = smf.ols(formula, data).fit().aic
            aics_with_candidates.append((aic, candidate))
        aics_with_candidates.sort(reverse=True)
        best_new_score, best_candidate = aics_with_candidates.pop()
        if current_aic < best_new_aic:
            remaining.remove(best_candidate)
            selected.append(best_candidate)
            current_aic = best_new_aic
    formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response, ' + '.join(selected))
    model = smf.ols(formula, data).fit()
    return model
```

The problem is the result is always a formula like this: `y~x+1`. It's selecting the best `x` (lowest AIC) for `y~x+1`, but not the formula: `y~x1+x2+..+1` with lowest AIC.

Comment: Is there a typo since `best_new_score` is assigned but never used? And can you post data and all `import`lines for a reproducible question? Interesting question but hard to help without data.